# Certain sections in slack-api blocks don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

Trying this example payload in block-kit builder doesn't work when using it in python.
Reason being it doesn't recognise some values in type `tags`, possibly emoji=True. But sending the payload formatting it to json string also doesn't work. I have to remove certain sections in the blocks which create the problem.

As per this example Slack API takes blocks as a Dictionary
https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/c9dc6aa0907a72c16cf36aa15e7e80031a9fdce2/integration_tests/samples/basic_usage/sending_a_message.py

The block-kit which gives an error when used in python code

```
https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T09D77D4P#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22Hello,%20Assistant%20to%20the%20Regional%20Manager%20Dwight!%20*Michael%20Scott*%20wants%20to%20know%20where%20you'd%20like%20to%20take%20the%20Paper%20Company%20investors%20to%20dinner%20tonight.%5Cn%5Cn%20*Please%20select%20a%20restaurant:*%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22divider%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Farmhouse%20Thai%20Cuisine*%5Cn:star::star::star::star:%201528%20reviews%5Cn%20They%20do%20have%20some%20vegan%20options,%20like%20the%20roti%20and%20curry,%20plus%20they%20have%20a%20ton%20of%20salad%20stuff%20and%20noodles%20can%20be%20ordered%20without%20meat!!%20They%20have%20something%20for%20everyone%20here%22%7D,%22accessory%22:%7B%22type%22:%22image%22,%22image_url%22:%22https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/c7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A/o.jpg%22,%22alt_text%22:%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Kin%20Khao*%5Cn:star::star::star::star:%201638%20reviews%5Cn%20The%20sticky%20rice%20also%20goes%20wonderfully%20with%20the%20caramelized%20pork%20belly,%20which%20is%20absolutely%20melt-in-your-mouth%20and%20so%20soft.%22%7D,%22accessory%22:%7B%22type%22:%22image%22,%22image_url%22:%22https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/korel-1YjNtFtJlMTaC26A/o.jpg%22,%22alt_text%22:%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*Ler%20Ros*%5Cn:star::star::star::star:%202082%20reviews%5Cn%20I%20would%20really%20recommend%20the%20%20Yum%20Koh%20Moo%20Yang%20-%20Spicy%20lime%20dressing%20and%20roasted%20quick%20marinated%20pork%20shoulder,%20basil%20leaves,%20chili%20&%20rice%20powder.%22%7D,%22accessory%22:%7B%22type%22:%22image%22,%22image_url%22:%22https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/DawwNigKJ2ckPeDeDM7jAg/o.jpg%22,%22alt_text%22:%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22divider%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22actions%22,%22elements%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22button%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22Farmhouse%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22click_me_123%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22button%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22Kin%20Khao%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22click_me_123%22,%22url%22:%22https://google.com%22%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22button%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22Ler%20Ros%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22click_me_123%22,%22url%22:%22https://google.com%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D
```

Payload creating an issue

```
block = [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "Hello, <lob> Team, Varanus wants you to know the Seo Anomalies Found.\n\n *Please review the Notifications below:*"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "divider"
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Farmhouse Thai Cuisine*\n:star::star::star::star: 1528 reviews\n They do have some vegan options, like the roti and curry, plus they have a ton of salad stuff and noodles can be ordered without meat!! They have something for everyone here"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/c7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A/o.jpg",
            "alt_text": "alt text for image"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Kin Khao*\n:star::star::star::star: 1638 reviews\n The sticky rice also goes wonderfully with the caramelized pork belly, which is absolutely melt-in-your-mouth and so soft."
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/korel-1YjNtFtJlMTaC26A/o.jpg",
            "alt_text": "alt text for image"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Ler Ros*\n:star::star::star::star: 2082 reviews\n I would really recommend the  Yum Koh Moo Yang - Spicy lime dressing and roasted quick marinated pork shoulder, basil leaves, chili & rice powder."
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/DawwNigKJ2ckPeDeDM7jAg/o.jpg",
            "alt_text": "alt text for image"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "divider"
    },
    {
        "type": "tags",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Farmhouse"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Kin Khao"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Ler Ros"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

response = client.chat_postMessage(blocks=block, text="A New Notification", channel="Channel-ID")
```

**Without the tags section i.e ("type" : "tags"), it works**

```
block = [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "Hello, <lob> Team, Varanus wants you to know the Seo Anomalies Found.\n\n *Please review the Notifications below:*"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "divider"
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Farmhouse Thai Cuisine*\n:star::star::star::star: 1528 reviews\n They do have some vegan options, like the roti and curry, plus they have a ton of salad stuff and noodles can be ordered without meat!! They have something for everyone here"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/c7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A/o.jpg",
            "alt_text": "alt text for image"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Kin Khao*\n:star::star::star::star: 1638 reviews\n The sticky rice also goes wonderfully with the caramelized pork belly, which is absolutely melt-in-your-mouth and so soft."
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/korel-1YjNtFtJlMTaC26A/o.jpg",
            "alt_text": "alt text for image"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Ler Ros*\n:star::star::star::star: 2082 reviews\n I would really recommend the  Yum Koh Moo Yang - Spicy lime dressing and roasted quick marinated pork shoulder, basil leaves, chili & rice powder."
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/DawwNigKJ2ckPeDeDM7jAg/o.jpg",
            "alt_text": "alt text for image"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "divider"
    }
]

response = client.chat_postMessage(blocks=block, text="A New Notification", channel="Channel-ID")
```

If I use json.dumps(block) or str(block), it gives and error `invalid_block`

Using the suggestions to use json.dumps(blocks) doesn't work.
[Slack API invalid_block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60344831/slack-api-invalid-block/76601814#76601814)

Any idea what is the right way to send blocks in python?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy-paste your blocks section into a Block Kit Builder as "Message Preview" layout, the validator will fail near the `"type": "tags"` with

```
Invalid value: "tags",
Must be one of: "actions", "condition", "context", "divider", "image"
"section", "header", "sticker", "contact_card", "share_shortcut"
"share_workflow", "video", "channel_set".
```

There is no such type of block with "Message" surface, in their reference: https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks, anyway, this is not existing type at all.

In original example this is a [`"type": "actions"` block](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#actions), that means it holds an array of interactive `elements` described in the [Reference: Block elements](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements).

So you need to use some of these block elements, not `tags`.

`emoji` Boolean is field of Text object usually with `type` = `plain_text` or `mrkdwn`.

Sending payloads like `client.chat_postMessage(blocks=block,...` is correct, `block` could be a standard Python object 'as-is', i.e. you don't need to manually serialize it with `json.dumps()`, just ensure you fill right primitives when copying+pasting from Block Kit Builder (i.e. use Python `True`/`False` instead of JS `true`/`false` etc.).

Comment: Would you know if its possible to create a block-kit template which is structured like column with headers. If there is something ready to use then nothing like it. I am able to send 50 sections in one block but it doesn't look nice.

Comment: AFAIK there is no any table-like or column-based advanced layout components, Block Kit design framework is actually pretty limited to the blocks, actions and UI components described in their docs and references.

If you need some nice structured layout you should format text with newlines and markdown elements like they use in their sample templates in the BK Builder. You can also separate sections with some delimiters like newlines or `"type": "divider"`, put content in different `section` blocks .